# in my php page, I need the visitor facebook information.. possible?

Tags: php, facebook

I see some website detect my facebook name and offer a like button so I can the page I'm visiting. Can that be done in php? if not, how then?

Thanks

Comment: A simple 'facebook api' in google would have done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook offers widgets for that matter, you can copy paste the code from the Facebook developer site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

To get a visitor's name, tou could use Facebook javascript API  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/. You'll need to create an application and the user will need to authorize it before you're able to get any information. There are obvious security reasons why you can't get your visitor's name.

Comment: so, I MUST use the widget.. no way to detect the visitor name for example: $fbName = $_SERVER['fbName'] ?

Comment: "There are obvious security reasons why you can't get your visitor's name" I'm just curious how these websites I visit got my name and picture without even ask me? is it a security whole in fb??

Comment: @KrayyemAlthwaini Do you have any example I could check out?